# Login Screen Password confirmation on one line

Tags: html, css, authentication, label, screen

So I am quite new to the whole HTML/CSS stuff,and most of the thing I have learned are either from here or googling questions I have,I am almost done with my assignment,but I can`t seem to figure out how to print two label words on the same line.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRdxs.png

```
[<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<style>
body {background-color: black;}
div {}
label {display:inline-block;width:235px;margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 20px; font-size: 25px; font-family: Calibre; color: white; text-align: left;}
input  {margin-top: 20px; margin-right: 20px;padding: 12px 20px;}
#main {border: 5px solid white; width: 600px; height: 400px;}
button {margin-left: 320px; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px; background-color:#00BB00; width:120px; height: 40px;
color: white;
font-size: 20px;
border-radius: 46px; 
-moz-border-radius: 46px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 46px; 
border: 0px solid #800000;
font-family: Calibre}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<form action="/web.engineering" method="post">
    <div>
    <label>Username:</label>
    <input type="text"placeholder="Username" name="username" required>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label>First name:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="First name" name="firstname" required>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label>Last name:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last name" name="lastname" required>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="password" required>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label>Passwordconfirmation:</label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Re-enter password" name="Repeat password" required>
    </div>
    <div>
    <button type="submit" ><b>Register</b></button>
    </div>
</form>

</div>

</body>
</html>][1]
```

So this is what I have and the picture is what I have to get.Can you please tell me how to print Password confirmation on the same line before the text box.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide an image of the expected output? or explain what is the problem even more?

Comment: Try with #main div having display:inline-block property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly give font-size according to space container div has and the second one use `display: flex;` with `flex-basis: 230px;`

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

div {}

#main form>div {
  display: flex;
}

label {
  flex-basis: 230px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-family: Calibre;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}

input {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
}

#main {
  border: 5px solid white;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}

button {
  margin-left: 320px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #00BB00;
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 46px;
  -moz-border-radius: 46px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 46px;
  border: 0px solid #800000;
  font-family: Calibre
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <form action="/web.engineering" method="post">
      <div>
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" required>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>First name:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="First name" name="firstname" required>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Last name:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Last name" name="lastname" required>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="password" required>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Password confirmation:</label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Re-enter password" name="Repeat password" required>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit"><b>Register</b></button>
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>

</body>

</html>]
```

Hope this will work!

Comment: @СимеонПецанов - your welcome, could you please give me vote up :)

Comment: I am with reputation below 15, the vote is recorded but is not visible.The moment i hit a reputation you should get your vote :( Sorry about that

Comment: No problem, gain more :)

Answer (score 0):

Make width of the labels larger or lower the font size of the label. Since you have fixed width, both words dont fit to the width of 235px in that font size. I tried with width 240px it's in the same row, and with 24px font-size it's in the same row.